# I have the following error when i coding my portfolio dex: Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: destroy is not a function

Tags: solidity, web3js, nextjs

***Hey guys! im coding a dex with foundry and nextjs using web3 library.
In my swap page i have the following error:Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: destroy is not a function. ***

Here is my code:

```
export default function Exchange() {
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const router = useRouter();
const [state, setState] = useState("buy");
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [token, setToken] = useState();
const [KittySwap, setKittySwap] = useState()
const [ethBalance, setEthBalance] = useState(0);
const [kicBalance, setKicBalance] = useState(0);
const [address, setAddress] = useState("0x0000000000");
// Load blockchain on page load
useEffect(async () => {
  await loadWeb3();
  await loadBlockchainData();
}, []);

const loadBlockchainData = async () => {
  const web3 = window.web3;
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  const _address = accounts[0];
  setAddress(_address);

  const _ethBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(_address);
  setEthBalance(_ethBalance);

  console.log(_ethBalance, _address);

  //Load Token
  const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
  const tokenData = Token.networks[networkId];
  if (tokenData) {
    const _token = new web3.eth.Contract(Token.abi, tokenData.address);
    setToken(_token);

    let _tokenBalance = await _token.methods.balanceOf(_address).call();
    setKicBalance(_tokenBalance);
    console.log(_tokenBalance);
  } else {
    alert("Please deploy the Token contract on the detected network");
  }

  //Load Kittyswap contract
  const kittyData = KittySwap.networks[networkId];
  if (kittyData) {
    const _kittySwap = new web3.eth.Contract(
      KittySwap.abi,
      kittyData.address
    );
    setKittySwap(_KittySwap);
  } else {
    window.alert(
      "Please deploy the KittySwap contract on the detected network"
    );
  }
};

const loadWeb3 = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    await window.ethereum.send("eth_requestAccounts");
    console.log("New browser");
  } else if (window.web3) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    console.log("Old browser");
  } else {
    alert("Non-Ethereum browser! Use Metamask");
  }
};

const buyTokens = async (value) => {
  let etherAmount = window.web3.utils.toWei(value, "Ether");
  let hash = await kittySwap.methods
    .buyTokens()
    .send({ value: etherAmount, from: address });
  console.log(hash);

  await loadBlockchainData();
};

const sellTokens = async (value) => {
  let kicAmount = window.web3.utils.toWei(value, "Ether");
  console.log(kittySwap._address, address, kicAmount);

  let hash = await token.methods
    .approve(kittySwap._address, kicAmount)
    .send({ from: address });
  console.log(hash);

  await kittySwap.methods.sellTokens(kicAmount).send({ from: address });
  console.log(hash);

  await loadBlockchainData();
};
```

Comment: Are you certain it's this bit of code that throws this error? it's not referencing a call to a `destroy` function anywhere. How did you narrow it down to that bit of code exactly? Surely your project is bigger than that.

Comment: I'm not sure at all but when I do the logic of the dex it gives me that error. If you want I can provide you what the powershell says. I think it is a problem from react-dom or something.

The window that throws the problem says "Call Stack
safelyCallDestroy
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (19753:0)"

and powershells says: "- warn ./node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'encoding' in 'E:\Programación\Web3\kittyswapv3\node_modules\node-fetch\lib'"